# How to animate arrow with CSS3 so that it looks like it would be growing?

Tags: css

I have the following picture of an arrow [image: arrow]

What I would like to achieve is to let this arrow arise (grow) via CSS.

How could I achieve this? I would prefer a CSS3 only solution if it was possible.

Comment: You want to do it on each event ? hover ? Take a look at the `transform: scale()` and `transition` properties.

Comment: "Looks like it would be growing" sounds opinion-based to me... Did you mean simply, "animate arrow so that it grows"?

Comment: What I would like to achieve is an animation which lets the shaft of the arrow grow.

Comment: A better word for _growing_ would be _drawing_ I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html > 
  <head> 
    <style type="text/css"> 

.zoomin img {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
      transition: all 2s ease;
      }

      .zoomin img:hover {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class="zoomin"> 
      <img src="img/image.png" /> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using **CSS3** `tranform` and `transition` properties :

HTML :

```
<img id="arrow" alt="arrow" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Pe8.png">
```

CSS :

```
#arrow {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

#arrow:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1coe7qs/)

Then you can play with other `transform` property values if you need a different effect (`rotate`, `translate`, `skew`, or more complex transformations).